# Spoofing IP HttpWebRequest C#

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, ip, spoofing

I was try to spoof my IP while using HttpWebRequest.
I've searched here for a solution and found this piece of code:

```
request.ServicePoint.BindIPEndPointDelegate = delegate { return new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("Spoofed IP Goes Here"), 0); };
```

Yet this code does not work for me, can you guys give me another solution?

Comment: That's totally impossible.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol

Comment: I hope you realize you're wasting your time.

Comment: Are you expecting the response or do you want the response to go to another IP?

Comment: I want the response to go to another IP

Comment: @RobbyDuke Is it possible to spoof IP using sockets and Raw socket type?

Comment: From [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address_spoofing): Some upper layer protocols provide their own defense against IP spoofing attacks. For example, Transmission Control Protocol (TCP) uses sequence numbers negotiated with the remote machine to ensure that arriving packets are part of an established connection. Since the attacker normally can't see any reply packets, the sequence number must be guessed in order to hijack the connection.

Comment: It is possible, yes. However you won't get any information back.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# How to spoof IP address for WebRequest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317513/c-sharp-how-to-spoof-ip-address-for-webrequest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done by using [SharpPCap](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sharppcap/). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7959380) answer by Evan.