# How to connect to a website through a proxy through java program

Tags: java, proxy

I am trying to create a computerized bot to hit a particular website through HTTP connection through different IPs mostly through proxies.

I have created script based on following code

```
System.getProperties().put( "proxySet", "true" );
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "<PROXY IP>");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "<PORT>");

ourURL = new URL("<TARGET WEBSITE>");
huc = (HttpURLConnection) ourURL.openConnection();
huc.setRequestMethod("GET");
```

But the problem in above code is when I check referring url, it takes my public IP only and not the proxy IP. Can someone help me in fixing this.

Comment: what does your proxy code do to remove the referring url.  The proxy may just be passing it through (or adding it).

Comment: I am checking referring url through the target website's analytics. If I am not wrong, this would be the path of bot. PROGRAM->MY PUBLIC IP->PROXY IP->TARGET WEBSITE. This was target website should take proxy IP.

Comment: But unless your proxy is written to hide such information then it would still remain.  There are other uses for proxy servers other than just to hide your ip address.

Comment: So you say that there is no way I can hide my IP. Basically I am trying out to create artificial visitors for the target website from different IPs. This is only for experimental purpose only if it can be done.

Comment: Yes, there are some proxy servers which will do exactly what you want. Try searching for `hide my ip address proxy server`

Comment: see http://whatismyipaddress.com/proxy-server

Comment: This is through website. Also it shows unknown IP. How can we do it through code. Like say I have 100 proxy IPs in my db and want to hit the website through these IPs on a certain interval.

Comment: You mean you want to use false ip addresses rather than having the ip address stripped?

Comment: If so see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317513/c-sharp-how-to-spoof-ip-address-for-webrequest

Answer (score 1):

As of java 1.5, you need to use something like the code below for proxy before openConnection:

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "proxy.****.com");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "####");
 Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator() {
                public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return (new PasswordAuthentication("user",
                            "pwd".toCharArray()));
                }
            };
Authenticator.setDefault(authenticator);
```

Comment: Sorry I am not seeing from the OP's question about any trouble with Authentication.