# How to send or forward a raw TCP packet by C# Socket on a Windows Server?

Tags: c#, windows, sockets, tcp, packet

I already know that it is not possible to send raw TCP packet on windows desktops witch mentioned on Microsoft Web Site, But is it possible on new **Windows Servers** like Windows Server 2019. I don't want to use Pcap or third-party drivers.

Something like this?

```
      var sendSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.IP);
        sendSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.MulticastTimeToLive, 8);
        sendSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);

        var s = new IPv4Header
        {
            SrcIpAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.99"),
            DesIpAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.90"),
            Protocol = 6,
            Length = (ushort)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(IPv4Header))
        };

        data = s.ToBytes();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Send Raw IP packet in C#, everything above the ethernet layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5652226/send-raw-ip-packet-in-c-everything-above-the-ethernet-layer)

Comment: @AliBigdeli, no it doesn't. They all using third party drivers not socket. Microsoft says it is not possible on Windows Desktop via socket, the question is what about Windows Server?

Comment: It is the c# managed library that blocks raw TCP.