# Sending IP packets

Tags: c#, java, c++, sockets, packets

I'm lost. I've been searching the web for days now and I just can't find the answer. I'm more or less a beginner socket programmer but I do understand it.

I want to do the following things:

1. Create a custom packet (from scratch, setting every value)
2. Send it

Either Java, C++ or C#. Is there an easy to use library for this or is there a core class that allows me to? I've already tried the Java library jnetpcap but that only gave me errors, even when running the examples and following the installation guide for eclipse.

Any help is much appreciated!

Note: It's for windows

Comment: Do you want to know how to design the packet structure? or you have already decided the packet structure but dont know how to implement it

Comment: You don't specify how 'custom' your packet has to be but I think you want [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964013/how-send-raw-ethernet-packet-with-c).

Comment: @SemVanmeenen Yeah that's exactly what I need! I still prefer Java or C++ over C# so if you have any c++ or java alternatives that would be good, if not i'll go for this, thanks!

Comment: I would suggest using Raw Sockets is a fairly advanced topic (something most developers with ten years experience using plain socket won't touch) and at a minimum you should use them after you have very good understanding of how plain sockets work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jNetPcap is an API based on WinPcap, just install WinPcap and it will work :)

As an alternative, you can try to use other libraries such as [Jpcap](https://github.com/jpcap/jpcap) (for Java) and [SharpPcap](https://github.com/chmorgan/sharppcap) (for C#)

Comment: I'm trying Jpcap now but I'm not sure how to send a packet to another server. Could you help?

Comment: Take a look at [Project](http://www.mediafire.com/?lighjmnm4ez), it's my project using Jpcap to send & capture packets.

Comment: I think Jpcap worked for me, even though I'm not sure how I can really test if the packets arrive..

Comment: Just use Wireshark to capture it :)

Comment: Can it sniff outgoing packets as well?

Answer (score 4):

Java: Socket

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html

Java: Raw sockets

http://www.savarese.com/software/rocksaw/

C#: TCPClient

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

C#: Raw sockets

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx

It should be fairly easy looking up examples of all four.

Comment: I've looked into both, but I don't think they'll allow me to build packets from scratch really. Sorry for the unclear question

Answer (score 3):

I have used sockets in c++ using winsock in windows and socket bsd in linux.

This was the best guide I found http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/index.html

**EDIT:** Beej's guide has everything: background information, simple examples,  advanced topics like data packing and some humour

Comment: +1 for Beej's guide, it really has everything you need to know. You can buy it as a paperback too.

Comment: Beej's guide has everything: background information, simple examples,  advanced topics like data packing and some humour

Answer (score 0):

Quite easy if u do it java.

for starters. http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/clientServer.html

Answer (score 0):

Tim,

Every packet needs a Fixed Length header followed by the Body and optionally a trailer. The fixed head length header should have details like the Packet Length(Body Length + Trailer Length), Time stamp, Unique Packet Id (Used to break the big packet into multiple small packets).

The receiver will always read the fixed length header first and determine the packet length and read the rest of the packet.

You need to append the size before every variable length elements like name etc.

Example of simple Packet Structure:

Header Size - 1 Byte

Sending details like Name, ID, Sex

Header

[8] - 1 Byte //size (Name Length + Name + Id + Sex)

Body

[5] - 1 Byte //Name Length

[Jeeva] - N Bytes

[1000] - 1 Byte ID

[0] -  1 Byte Sex (0 - Male, 1- Female)

Note: You need to be careful about Endianess. Ask further questions for clarification

Comment: +1 and -1 for making me smile.