# Ethernet Frames or MAC Broadcasts with C# or C in windows (xp)

Tags: c#, windows, networking, broadcast, ethernet

after reading:

[How send raw ethernet packet with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964013/how-send-raw-ethernet-packet-with-c)

I still have questions:

Is it possible to do broadcasts or send your own ethernet frames on layer 2 with C# or C without having winpcap installed or/and without manipulating the installed drivers?

As for Broadcast, I could run a process with the `arp -a` command and parse its output, maybe it will work.

But still the issue with the ethernet packets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't... at least not directly as you are asking.

Windows provides no API to access layer 2 directly.  To do this, you would need to write an NDIS protocol driver.  If you are interested in taking on this task, start here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff557050(v=vs.85).aspx

For utility-like software, the best thing to do is to bundle one of the drivers listed in that question you linked to.

Comment: hi, thx i read about the NDIS drivers. The problem with them would be they also have to be installed? (or not?) I need a installationless routine

Comment: @Gobliins, I don't believe that is possible.  However, if you have the right permissions, you should be able to install and uninstall the drivers on the fly.  There would be a UAC prompt, but that's it.  I'm not positive, but I don't believe a reboot would be necessary.

Comment: hey are you still here? Do you know if it would be possible just to receive and read Ethernet Packets from Windows without the special drivers?

Comment: Well we talked about manipulating (which makes sense because of security issoes), not just read. But from your answer i guess it´s also not possible.

Comment: @Gobliins, My apologies, I misread your follow-up question.  Yes, to my knowledge, there is no direct way to receive layer-2 broadcasts without a driver.